# Use segmented control to switch *and refresh* subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a segmented control to supplement a tab controller and add extra options within that section.

[image]

The segmented control switches between three containers, each of which has an embedded tableviewcontainer and i flip between them by showing / hiding as necessary:

```
@IBOutlet var listPicker: UISegmentedControl! 
@IBOutlet var dueView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var nextView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var doneView: UIView!

switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0: 
        dueView.hidden = false
        nextView.hidden = true
        doneView.hidden = true
    ...
    }
```

Each view is linked to a UITableViewController in the storyboard:

[image]

Rather than just showing (unhiding) the view (which is working), is there a way to refresh its' content too in the same way as the tab bar controller does?

Comment: are all those views containing UITableView?

Comment: They contain UITableViewControllers. I'll add a screenshot of the storyboard.

Comment: I would avoid creating layers, I would have one UITableViewController inside UINavigationController, and segmentedControl would change data source and delegate

Comment: do not play around with show/hide. just reset the tableview datasource objects and reload it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First print the following:

```
print(self.childViewControllers)
```

Then you will know the Child indices of your `ViewController` then use the following

```
    @IBAction func segmentValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {


        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
  case 0:
       dueView.hidden = false
        nextView.hidden = true
        doneView.hidden = true
 // create object from your nextView and refresh it
    var myClass : ViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! ViewController
    myClass.tableView.reloadData()
    myClass.viewWillAppear(false)

   break;


  default:
    break;
       }


    }
```

Lets say you have the following containers and its holding `ViewControllers` :

```
dueView.hidden = false
nextView.hidden = true
doneView.hidden = true
```

If its sorted inside the view of storyboard like that 1- dueView then 2-nextView 3- doneView then the indices should be but again it all depends on how you sorted them to show:

```
 dueView : self.childViewControllers[0]
 nextView : self.childViewControllers[1]
 doneView : self.childViewControllers[2]
```

**Update:**

Since you have Navigation controller before your view controller then you might need to cast to get the topview controller and then reload the data.

Good luck !